# How to set Views Vertically under each other Programmatically and Download file on Button Click

Tags: android

**I have two questions**

**First**, I have a for loop, with every element in this loop i want to set the Name String as a **TextView** and the Url to a **Button**,
Then to position those TextViews and Buttons vertically under each other **Programmatically**.

**Second**, i want those buttons to work *for e.g* if i click it then start downloading some from it's url.

To be clear this is my **for loop**

```
for(int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {

    // This contains a String
    String Name = "...";

    // This contains a video url that i want to download onClick
    String Url = "...";

}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create linearLayout and place your elements int it

do it like

```
for(int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {

    // This contains a String
String Name = "...";

    // This contains a video url that i want to download onClick
String Url = "...";
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(context);
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
Button b = new Button(context);

ll.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
ll.addView(tv);
tv.setText(Name);
ll.addView(b);
b.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener() {
                             @Override
                             public void onClick(View v) {
                                downloadVideo(url);
                             }
                         });
addView(ll);
}
```

to Download url you can use alot of methods like the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)